# Powershell download image using current user credentials

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-on-prem

I have a SharePoint2013 url, i need to download two image files and compare its size in powershell.

Is it possible to compare two image file's size and dimensions without downloading it to local

Or

If we have to download how to do it using current user credentials in powershell or management shell. 
I don't want to use Get-credentials to have a popup.
Also i cannot hard code password due to security.

Thanks in advance,
Gokul

Answer (score 0):

**Option A (not tested)**

With metadata extraction on images (for jpg, png) it should work to directly compare the images.

Create a column with the name "wic_YResolution" and "wic_XResolution" (you can rename those later). This guy got it working:
[Link 1](http://www.sandeepnakarmi.com/2012/09/promoting-image-metadata-values-to-sharepoint-asset-library/)

**Option B**

You can modify this script to download images. I used it to download all the images from a library. It doesn't ask for credentials. 
[Link 2](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Bulk-Export-SharePoint-51857b22)

**Bonus**

You can use Export-CliXml to save credentials securely. [Link 3](https://www.jaapbrasser.com/quickly-and-securely-storing-your-credentials-powershell/)